# jQuery .on() Method Not Working In Chrome (but does in IE & FF)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-chrome, dom

I have jQuery code that executes fine in both IE 9 & FF 19, but doesn't seem to work properly in Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172. Using jQuery 1.7.1

I have 2 dropdown lists and a button. On initial page load, click event handlers get wired up to the option elements in both ddlists and the button via jQuery. In both IE and FF, the event handlers fire for all 3 events. Works great. However, in Chrome, only the button event handler gets fired - NOT the click event handlers for the select options.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ddlCategory').on('click', 'option', function (event) {

        // BREAKPOINT ON FIRST LINE IN THIS BLOCK NEVER HITS WHILE IN CHROME BUT DOES IN IE & FF
        if ($(event.target).val() == -1)
            return;
       more code...
    });

    $('#ddlSubCategory').on('click', 'option', function (event) {
        ResetSubCatOptionDisplay();
        var selectedId = $(event.target).val();           
        more code....
       // BREAKPOINT ON FIRST LINE IN THIS BLOCK NEVER HITS WHILE IN CHROME BUT DOES IN IE & FF
    });

    $('#btnAddSubCat').click(function (event) {
        ManageWarningDisplay(false, "");

        more code...
        // BREAKPOINT ALWAYS HITS ON FIRST LINE IN THIS BLOCK FOR ALL 3 BROWSERS
     });

    more code ..... 

});
```

I thought maybe the 'on()' function doesn't work in Chrome, so I also tried using the following syntax, but again, same results. Doesn't seem to be wiring up the handler at all as the breakpoints don't hit in Chrome Dev Tools like it does for the button's event handler.

```
    $('#ddlCategory option').click(function (event) { ...
```

Thinking that Chrome might not like click events on 'option' elements, I thought about trying to wire event handler to select element itself, but then it fires even when user clicks the down arrow.

REASONS I'M USING THE EVENTS: I don't want to use the 'onchange' event since it doesn't fire when the user clicks on the one and only option in the select (if there's only one in certain cases, which there will be). Plus, for the ddlSubCategory control, I will be dynamically removing and adding option elements to it on the client at runtime so I needed to use $().on() or $().live() (latter is deprecated) to delegate to future options.

Anyone have any ideas on this???

Comment: can you make a js fiddle for this?

Comment: Why a click event on the option element instead of an change event on the select that contains it? Also, do all these options exist on page load?

Comment: An option does not fire click events in Chrome.

Comment: You should be using the `change` event for options, not the click event.

Comment: As I've explained at the bottom of my original post, I didn't use the change event on the select itself because if there's only one option in the select (and at times, there might be), then the change event doesn't fire. The click event on the select itself fires even when an option isn't clicked. Not sure what the solution is here.

Comment: Use a 'default option' in the select so there is always a selection to be made (thus you can guarantee a `change` event (assuming it's a required field)? We use `<option value="">[select]</option>` as our default (though sometimes context changes what makes sense as the display value)

Comment: Here's a **JSFiddle** as requested: [http://jsfiddle.net/vp46y/](http://jsfiddle.net/vp46y/) . As you can see, executing it in FF or IE works fine, but not in Chrome.

Comment: BLSully and Adeneo, you should post as answers because the combination of your two comments, really is the answer. Chrome doesn't fire click events for OPTION elements and therefore, need to use the Change event AND have a default " -- Make A Selection --" option to ensure a "change" is fired. THANKS ALL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event is not valid on options. It's valid on select though, so that's the workaround:

```
$("select#yourSelect").change(function(){
    process($(this).children(":selected").html());
});
```

Comment: So Chrome does not raise a click event for an option element like IE and FF does. So the solution was to use the change event on the select and then make sure there's a default "--Make A Selection--" option always available that way if there's only one valid option to select (click on) the change event will fire.

Comment: yep - although one question: how is it possible to have only ONE option? I mean, in that case shouldn't you either not present this option at all or have it selected by default?

Comment: Per requirements, as items are chosen from the dropdown they are removed from the list dynamically.

Comment: Based on this answer, my problem in Chrome was solved. I chose to capture the text into a variable:
`var opt = jQuery(this).children(":selected").text();